Determining whether a certain class of algebras is a quasi-variety
Normally, problems/questions in universal algebra deal with arbitrary signatures, in full generality, for example Birkhoff's HSP theorem, or they deal with some fixed signature and study which sorts of properties different varieties with these signature can have. I have a slightly different question, which is whether one can expand the signature of a certain quasi-variety, add in some equations, and obtain a true variety which retains some desirable traits of the quasi-variety. Specifically, I am working with algebras over the signature
$$\mathbb{R} \cup \{*\} $$
Where each real number is a unary symbol, and $*$ is nullary. Now I would like my algebras to have the property that for any two distinct real numbers $r_1,r_2$ we have the implication
$$r_1(x)=r_2(x) \implies x = * $$
But adding this as an axiom results in a quasi-variety. However, the variety of vector spaces does satisfy this property (With $*$ replaced by $\mathbf{0}$), i.e. it can be deduced from only the vector space axioms, but this deduction crucially relies on the binary operation of vector addition, and the fact that elements have inverses with respect to this operation. It also uses the compatibility axiom
$$r_1(r_2(x)) = r_1r_2(x) $$
I specifically want the compatibility axiom to not be included in the axioms for my quasi-variety, and I also want the following implication to be independent of the axioms, as it is too restrictive:
$$r(x) = r(y) \implies x = y $$
However, any subset, or weakening of the vector space axioms seems to either be unable to prove
$$r_1(x)=r_2(x) \implies x = * $$
Or it proves all three properties. Hence my question is:
Is there some reason that in a variety where we have the implication (for non-zero $r$)
$$r_1(x)=r_2(x) \implies x = * $$
We also have the implication
$$r(x) = r(y) \implies x = y \ ?$$
If the answer is no, is there an example of a variety (where you are free to enlarge the signature from $\mathbb{R}\cup \{*\}$) where one is able to deduce the former implication, but wherein the latter is independent?
Note: Although I would like the compatibility axiom to be independent from the axioms, the following weakening is unproblematic, though seemingly not very useful:
$$r(r^{-1}(r(x))) = r(x) $$

Not sure about your question, but vector spaces don’t form a variety since fields don’t form a variety. Maybe this affects the answer to your question.

@JoD17 vector spaces over a fixed field do form a variety. We implement the scalar multiplication as a family of unary operations $c\cdot -$, one for each scalar $c$ in the field.

@AlexKruckman Ah I see. That figures with the posters comment about the signature they are working in. My mistake!

Your signature is $\mathbb R \cup {}$, that is you have only unary and nullary operations, right? (Where $0$ is also a nullary, although perhaps it could also be seen as unary?). It seems like the algebra $(\mathbb R\cup{}, (r)_{r \in \mathbb R},)$, where $$ is some element not belonging to $\mathbb R$ and the operations are given by $r(x)=r$, for $x \in \mathbb R$ and $r()=$ has the property that $r(x)=r(y)$ doesn't imply $x=y$, but if $r(x)=s(x)$ for all operations $r,s$ and for some $x\in\mathbb R\cup{}$, then $x=$. It seems to me that this answers your question.

@amrsa, this does not answer my question, this is a particular algebra wherein the one implication is true, and the other is false, I am asking for a variety where the first statement is true in each instance of the variety, and the second statement is independent, i.e. true in some algebras, but false in others

Can you state more precisely what you're looking for? The variety of vector spaces satisfies your first implication (for all $r_1\neq r_2$) but not your second one (when $r=0$). Maybe you should ask for a variety satisfying the first implication but such that there are at least $2$ real numbers where the second implication fails? Also, the title of your question doesn't seem to match the body.

Here's a precise and simplified version of your question: Is there a variety of algebras $V$ whose signature contains unary functions $f$ and $g$ and a constant $$ such that (a) the implication $f(x)=g(x)\implies x=$ holds in all algebras in $V$, and (b) there is an algebra $A\in V$ such that the interpretations of $f$ and $g$ in $A$ both fail to be injective? Would an answer to this satisfy you?

@AlexKruckman, thank you for making it precise,  I specify at a later instance that $r\neq 0$, I'll add it to the first appearance of this implication. This is certainly on track to answering my question, but I would like uncountably many unary symbols. And furthermore, it should only be independent that any particular interpretation is injective, hence it is sufficient to find an algebra for each symbol, rather than one where they are all non-injective simultaneously

I'll answer the simplified version of your question I proposed in the comments:

Is there a variety of algebras $V$ whose signature contains unary functions $f$ and $g$ and a constant $*$ such that (a) the implication $f(x) = g(x)\implies x = *$ holds in all algebras in $V$, and (b) there is an algebra $A\in V$ such that the interpretations of $f$ and $g$ in $A$ both fail to be injective?

Consider the variety $V$ in the signature $\{f,g,h,*\}$, where $*$ is $0$-ary, $f$ and $g$ are $1$-ary, and $h$ is $2$-ary, with the following axioms:

$h(f(x),g(x)) = x$.
$h(x,x) = *$.

Let $A\in V$, $a\in A$, and suppose $f(a) = g(a)$. Then $a = h(f(a),g(a)) = h(g(a),g(a)) = *$, so your first implication is satisfied.
It remains to find an algebra $A$ in $V$ such that the intepretations of $f$ and $g$ are not injective. Let $A = \{*,a,b\}$. Interpret $*$ as $*$, $f(*) = g(*) = f(a) = g(b) = *$, $g(a) = a$, and $f(b) = b$. Now set $h$ so that $h(*,a) = a$, $h(b,*) = b$, and $h(x,y) = *$ for all other pairs $(x,y)$.
It is easy to check that the defining equations of $V$ are satisfied in $A$, but neither $f$ nor $g$ is injective.

Interesting! Thank you for your answer. I seems like adding this binary $h$ into the signature $\mathbb{R}\cup {0}$ and the corresponding equations for all distinct pairs of real numbers also does the trick, but now I wonder which algebras in the quasi-variety are reducts of algebras in this variety with the added binary symbol, and this is where the title of my question comes from, it does not seem obvious that any quasi-variety is not just some variety where you "forget" some symbols...But I struggle to formulate this question, I would appreciate some advice on doing so as well

@Carlyle For the latter question, you'll probably find some interesting information in Remarks on reducts of varieties by Stanley Burris.

Thank you, this is exactly the question I was thinking about!
